# Strange Problem Browsing Blocked Websites‏

Tags: configuration, vpn, raspberry-pi

Today I have installed Tor on my Raspberry Pi and also set it up as a relay. I can monitor tor traffic using arm so it means it is working. My `SocksPort` configuration is  9050, 192.168.1.187:9050 where 192.168.1.187 is internal IP of my Raspberry Pi.
In order to anonymize my browsing traffic on my main windows PC, I configured Firefox to use my Raspberry Pi as proxy on port 9050. When I visit the page https://check.torproject.org/, it says my configuration is successful and I see different IP address.

From that point I assume everything should work properly but if I try to browse web sites that are blocked in my country such as YouTube it just does not connect. However if I use VPN I can see those blocked web sites.

So could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my configuration? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 2):

Despite setting the SOCKS5 proxy in Firefox, I could not view web pages blocked in my country because Firefox was still doing DNS lookup out of my router, rather than through Tor.

Asking on the tor-relays mailing list, I learned this solution. Type "about:config" in the address bar, and hit enter. Search for the item "network.proxy.socks_remote_dns" and set its value as true. That directs DNS lookup through Tor.

Comment: Please try to enhance your answer a bit. Maybe you can link to the tor-relays mailing list and explain what the options in your answer do.

Comment: Jens you are right, i wrote the comment above in a hurry. Despite setting proxy for Firefox I could not view the web pages blocked in my country because Firefox was still doing DNS lookup out of my router, which is default behavior of Firefox. In order to change this, you should write about:config in the address bar and hit the enter. In the opening list find the item network.proxy.socks_remote_dns and set its value as true. That is it...

Comment: @Ferdi Just a **note regarding your accounts:** You are using "unregistered" accounts which are generated automatically and the credentials to access them are stored only in cookies of your browser. This means the following: Removing the cookies makes the account inaccessible (without admin cooperation). Accessing Stack Exchange from a different browser without the cookies synced requires creation of a new (auto) account. Consequently you will not be able to comment and directly edit your own posts without gaining enough of reputation. Also your reputation will not be summed together.

Comment: If your DNS lookups did not go through Tor, then you could also not connect to any .onion site.